# Getting mergeDebugResources error while running ionic build android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am getting following error while running **ionic build android** command. I spent hours to google it, but could not get any solution. Please help guys.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wron Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
>   D:\Ionic_Workspace\MyProject_Dev\MyProject_Workspace_1.1\MyProject 1.1\platforms\and
>   roid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\9.6.1\res\drawable-t
>   vdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png: Error:
>   File path too long on Windows, ke ep below 240 characters :
>   D:\Ionic_Workspace\MyProject_Dev\MyProject_Workspace_1.1\MyProject
>   1.1\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-b
>   ase\9.6.1\res\drawable-tvdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --info or --debug option to get more l og output. Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed with an
>   exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
>   D:\Ionic_Workspace\MyProject_Dev\MyProject_Workspace_1.1\MyProject 1.1\platforms\and
>   roid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\9.6.1\res\drawable-t
>   vdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png: Error:
>   File path too long on Windows, ke ep below 240 characters :
>   D:\Ionic_Workspace\MyProject_Dev\MyProject_Workspace_1.1\MyProject
>   1.1\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-b
>   ase\9.6.1\res\drawable-tvdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png
>
> Try:Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --info or --debug option to get more l og output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend verified error stack, and he identified a problem

Let us go through line which is mentioned in error above,

> Error: File path too long on Windows, keep below 240 characters :

So basically Windows only allows 240 character limit for a path. So he updated  path for project and finally we solved the problem. Hope it will help somebody!!