# Android mergeDebugResources failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

### Not a duplicate

I've read a lot of different SO posts with "similar" problems, but so far nothing has resolved my issue:

- [Android Studio - mergeDebugResources exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121033/android-studio-mergedebugresources-exception)
- [Android Studio mergeDebugResources issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339441/android-studio-mergedebugresources-issue)
- [Ionic: Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources' (Some file crunching failed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545711/ionic-execution-failed-for-task-mergedebugresources-some-file-crunching-fai)
- [gradlew build freezing at mergeDebugResources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879730/gradlew-build-freezing-at-mergedebugresources)
- [Getting mergeDebugResources error while running ionic build android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018511/getting-mergedebugresources-error-while-running-ionic-build-android)
- etc

It seems like this one particular step (mergeDebugResources) can fail spectacularly in hundreds of different ways and ***never*** gives a helpful error message. At best it tells you nothing and at worst it gives you misleading information that sends you in the wrong direction trying to debug your problems.

### What I'm doing

I'm writing a small wrapper around ExoPlayer. My wrapper exposes a custom View with properties that are passed directly to ExoPlayer's `PlayerView`. The `attrs.xml` file for my custom view looks like this:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="BFPlayer">
        <!-- PlayerView attributes -->
        <!-- I wish these were camelCase and not snake_case, but c'est la vie -->
        <attr name="use_artwork" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="default_artwork" format="reference" />
        <attr name="use_controller" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="hide_on_touch" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="auto_show" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="hide_during_ads" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="show_buffering" format="enum">
            <enum name="never" value="0" />
            <enum name="when_playing" value="1" />
            <enum name="always" value="2" />
        </attr>
        <attr name="resize_mode" format="enum">
            <enum name="fit" value="0" />
            <enum name="fixed_width" value="1" />
            <enum name="fixed_height" value="2" />
            <enum name="fill" value="3" />
            <enum name="zoom" value="4" />
        </attr>
        <attr name="surface_type" format="enum">
            <enum name="none" value="0" />
            <enum name="surface_view" value="1" />
            <enum name="texture_view" value="2" />
            <enum name="spherical_view" value="3" />
        </attr>
        <attr name="shutter_background_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="keep_content_on_player_reset" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="player_layout_id" format="reference" />
        <attr name="controller_layout_id" format="reference" />
        <!-- BFPlayer attributes -->
        <!-- snake_case to match ExoPlayer attributes -->
        <attr name="video_src" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

### What's happening

I'm getting the following error when trying to build my project:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  /Users/stevenbarnett/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/906c495794baffdd076b02fc420f6298/res/values/values.xml:726:5-730:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/resize_mode' with config ''.

  /Users/stevenbarnett/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/906c495794baffdd076b02fc420f6298/res/values/values.xml:726:5-730:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

  /Users/stevenbarnett/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/906c495794baffdd076b02fc420f6298/res/values/values.xml:726:5-730:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/surface_type' with config ''.

  /Users/stevenbarnett/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/906c495794baffdd076b02fc420f6298/res/values/values.xml:726:5-730:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

  /Users/stevenbarnett/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/1694e02eca6cc0cfe670672c5973bd19/res/values/values.xml:32:5-36:373: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/show_buffering' with config ''.

  /Users/stevenbarnett/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/1694e02eca6cc0cfe670672c5973bd19/res/values/values.xml:32:5-36:373: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

  /Users/stevenbarnett/Source/BluePlayer/AndroidSDK/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml: error: file failed to compile.
```

Notice that it's claiming the value defined in `values.xml` from line 726 column 5 through line 730 column 25 "was previously defined" in `values.xml` from line 726 column 5 through line 730 column 25. It's literally seeing the same declaration!

I've tried:

- Cleaning my project
- Invalidating caches and restarting
- Deleting my `~/.gradle` directory
- Reinstalling Android Studio
- Downgrading Gradle Android Plugin (from `3.4.0` to `3.0.0`)
- Upgrading Gradle Android Plugin (from `3.4.0` to `3.5.0-beta1`)

I'm on Mac OS X (so any Windows-related issues are irrelevant)

I'm on a 64-bit machine, using 64-bit build tools

I have successfully built this project and many others before. The issue didn't arise until I tried to create this `attrs.xml` file. It's only the `enum` attributes that are throwing the error. Removing or renaming these attributes allows the project to build, however these are the names expected by ExoPlayer's `PlayerView` and so I cannot change them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an answer I'm happy with, but I do have an answer ***kind of*** for now.

For the `enum` values (and only the `enum` values) PlayerView's attributes were colliding with my own -- for some reason. Perhaps a quirk of how Android parses the attributes.xml file? I solved this by changing the names and then using methods on the PlayerView to set these values at instantiation:

**attrs.xml**

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="BFPlayer">
        <!-- PlayerView attributes -->
        <attr name="useArtwork" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="defaultArtwork" format="reference" />
        <attr name="useController" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="hideOnTouch" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="autoShow" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="hideDuringAds" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="showBuffering" format="enum">
            <enum name="never" value="0" />
            <enum name="when_playing" value="1" />
            <enum name="always" value="2" />
        </attr>
        <attr name="resizeMode" format="enum">
            <enum name="fit" value="0" />
            <enum name="fixed_width" value="1" />
            <enum name="fixed_height" value="2" />
            <enum name="fill" value="3" />
            <enum name="zoom" value="4" />
        </attr>
        <attr name="surfaceType" format="enum">
            <enum name="none" value="0" />
            <enum name="surface_view" value="1" />
            <enum name="texture_view" value="2" />
            <enum name="spherical_view" value="3" />
        </attr>
        <attr name="shutterBackgroundColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="keepContentOnPlayerReset" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="playerLayoutId" format="reference" />
        <attr name="controllerLayoutId" format="reference" />
        <!-- BFPlayer attributes -->
        <attr name="videoSrc" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**BFPlayer.java**

```
        this.setUseArtwork(attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.BFPlayer_useArtwork, true));
        this.setDefaultArtwork(attributes.getDrawable(R.styleable.BFPlayer_defaultArtwork));
        this.setUseController(attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.BFPlayer_useController, true));
        this.setControllerHideOnTouch(attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.BFPlayer_hideOnTouch, true));
        this.setControllerAutoShow(attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.BFPlayer_autoShow, true));
        this.setControllerHideDuringAds(attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.BFPlayer_hideDuringAds, true));
        this.setShowBuffering(attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.BFPlayer_showBuffering, true));
        this.setResizeMode(attributes.getInt(R.styleable.BFPlayer_resizeMode, AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT));
        this.setShutterBackgroundColor(attributes.getColor(R.styleable.BFPlayer_shutterBackgroundColor, Color.BLACK));
        this.setKeepContentOnPlayerReset(attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.BFPlayer_keepContentOnPlayerReset, false));
        this.setKeepScreenOn(attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.BFPlayer_keepScreenOn, true));
```

My problem with this solution is two-fold:

1. This duplicates the list of attributes between `attrs.xml` and `BFPlayer.java`, so if ExoPlayer adds a new attribute in a future release I'll have to remember to update ***two*** files instead of one
2. A few attributes lack corresponding methods. There is no `setSurfaceType` method, for instance. This means that I physically cannot change this value from the default. The default creates a video renderer even when dealing with audio-only content, which means I'll be wasting CPU cycles and battery life for no reason when playing audio-only content

Still, this is the best I could come up with.